# Create different .htm file for each loop

Tags: python, selenium

This is the first time, I am posting a question. Please forgive me if I do something incorrect.

I am trying to create a python-selenium script to get the source code of MULTIPLE web pages.

I am running the script in the following manner (via command line on windows 7)

**python program.py < input.txt > output.htm**

This does creates the result, however since I am using a loop function it is appending the same file with all the results.

Is there a way, I can create a **NEW FILE FOR EACH result/print**

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/office/Desktop/chromedriver' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
while(True):
url = raw_input("")
url2 = raw_input("")
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
browser.get(url2)
time.sleep(10)

element_to_hover_over = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="personSummaryTable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[5]/div/span[1]/a')
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
time.sleep(5)
stuff = browser.page_source.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print stuff
```

Jan's idea worked great,

All it needed was to let python decide a filename,
Thanks Jan

```
import datetime
suffix = ".html"
basename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
fname = "_".join([basename, suffix]) # e.g. 'mylogfile_120508_171442'
print fname
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    f.write(stuff)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly; python is sensitive to proper indentation.

Comment: Please ignore the indentation. I have it right in the .py file.

Its just that I am new here, and I couldn't paste it properly on stackoverflow.
But, Thanks for helping me out on that :)

Comment: There is still edit button and you should fix the indentation. Sometimes the bug is caused by wrong indentation and ignoring it altogether makes it impossible to see the bug! To paste a code block, copy paste it, then select all of it, and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome at SO

You have two options

## Let Python code decide on name of output file

This will likely be based on current time, e.g.

```
import time
# here get somehow your page content
page_content = ?????
prefix = "outut-"
suffix = ".html"
fname = "{prefix}{now:d}{suffix}".format(now=time.time())
print fname
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    f.write(page_content)
```

## Let your external loop (out of Python) create the file name

This file name can be e.g. on Linux created by some form of `date` command.

Comment: Hello Jan, Thanks for replying.
However, I am getting a key error when I am running the script.
Could you please advise?


fname = "{prefix}{now:d}{suffix}".format(now=time.time())
KeyError: 'prefix'

Comment: Thanks a tonnnnn!!!!!!!!!! Jan

It worked with a little move around. But your Idea was all that I needed :) Thanks again.


import datetime
 suffix = ".html"
 basename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
 fname = "_".join([basename, suffix]) # e.g. 'mylogfile_120508_171442'
 print fname
 with open(fname, "w") as f:
  f.write(stuff)